# iPhone ios4 - Replacing iPod dock icon whilst playing background audio stream

Tags: iphone, ios4, streaming, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I've figured out how I can get audio playing in the background on ios4, however I've noticed that some apps also replace the iPod dock icon with their own app icon. (Last.fm & Spotify for example).

They are also able to use the dock media controls to pause and resume their streams.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's easy you have to respond to the Remote Control Events. This also lets you control your app with the headset.

In lets say viewDidLoad call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

And you have to respond to both

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
return YES;
}
```

And

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    switch (event.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            if (audio.rate == 0.0) {
                [audio play];
            } else {
                [audio pause];
            }
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            [audio play];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            [audio pause];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks, I'll give it a try. do you have any ideas about replacing the iPod dock icon with my own app icon?

Comment: By implementing this Apple will putt your icon in the dock

Comment: In fact you must call becomeFirstResponder inside of viewDidAppear otherwise it doesn't work and you never receive remote control events. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456435/ios-4-remote-controls-for-background-audio – this post is more useful.