# iOS 4: Remote controls for background audio

Tags: iphone, audio, ios4, avfoundation

I'm currently attempting to set up background audio for an app I'm developing for iOS 4. The app doesn't have a dedicated music player `viewController`, however, unlike other background audio apps such as Pandora, which makes the task a bit more confusing.

I've set the appropriate `Info.plist` settings correctly and have an `AVAudioPlayer` object in my app delegate which is accessible from everywhere. When the user plays a song, I replace the `AVAudioPlayer` with a new one initialized with the song and play it. This all works great, except now I have no idea how to go about supporting remote control events.

Based on Apple's documentation, I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    switch(event.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            if([iPhoneAppDelegate backgroundAudioPlayer].playing)
                [iPhoneAppDelegate pauseBackgroundAudioPlayer];
            else
                [iPhoneAppDelegate playBackgroundAudioPlayer];
            break;
    }
}
```

The thing is, where do I put this? Apple's documentation seems to suggest this should go in some view controller somewhere, but my app has lots of view controllers and navigation controllers. Wherever I try to put this, for some reason tapping the Toggle Play/Pause button in the multitasking tray remote controls either causes the song to just pause for a moment and then unpause, or somehow causes the song to play twice.

Comment: How u changed the play/stop button in the mult-tasking bar?!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a couple of solutions to receiving global remote control events on the Apple Developer Forums after a bit of searching.

One way is to subclass `UIWindow` and override its `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:`.

The second, perhaps nicer way is to subclass `UIApplication` and override `sendEvent:`. That way, you can intercept all the remote control events and handle them there globally, and not have any other responders handle them later in the responder chain.

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
          // Handle event
     }
     else
          [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: See my comment to Brian Dam Pedersen's answer

Comment: An even nicer way to do this is to add it to the normal UIApplication in a category

Comment: I would recommend Brian's Answer

Answer (score 37):

The documentation examples are a bit misleading, but there is no need to subclass anything anywhere. The correct place to put remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: is in the application delegate, as it remains in the responder chain regardless of whether the app is in the foreground or not. Also the begin/end receiving remote control events should be based on whether you actually need the events, not on the visibility of some random view.

Comment: Completely correct. To get complete control of remote controls for your app (whether it's in foreground or background) you need to call beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, but that's not all. Your UIApplicationDelegate starts to receive remote control events after your app tells iOS that it's playing a track - by setting MPNowPlayingInfoCenter nowPlayingInfo property.

Comment: It is really great answer, I was stuck off from a week.

Comment: Putting remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: into the app delegate just doesn't work for me; I had to go with subclassing UIWindow.

Comment: Tip: remoteControlReceivedWithEvent wasn't working until I removed it's duplicate from UIViewController.

Comment: Putting remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: into the app delegate just didn't work for me either, until I realized that my app delegate (created from an xcode template back in the iOS2 days) is a subclass of NSObject. Once I switched my app delegate to a subclass of UIResponder -remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: started getting called.

Comment: Update: Putting remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: into the app delegate only works for me on iOS5, in order to get things to work in iOS4 I had to subclass UIWindow.

Comment: Just to enrich the answer. In the case of my tabbed bar application, on iOS6 putting the event control in the tabbar controller was working properly. On iOS7, instead, I had to move it in the applicationDelegate because I guess something changed in the way the OS manage that stuff. Now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks. Put remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: into the app delegate only works for me in iOS7/iOS8.

Answer (score 4):

The second method didn't work for me, `sendEvent` was never called. However the first method worked just nicely (subclassing `UIWindow`).

Comment: Works like a charm. I want to add that beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents can be called inside of app delegate to subscribe for remote control event.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this one for a while and none of the answers above worked. The bug in my code, and I hope that it will help someone reading this, was that I had the AudioSession set to mix with others. You want to be the foreground audio player to get Remote Control events. Check to see if you have INCORRECT code like this:

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
    UInt32 doSetProperty = 0;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
                             sizeof (doSetProperty),
                             &doSetProperty
                             );
    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
```

And remove the AudioSessionSetProperty, or change doSetProperty to 1.

Answer (score 0):

No need to subclass Window or forward events.  Simply handle it from your main view controller.  See the Audio Mixer (MixerHost) example for details.

http://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/#samplecode/MixerHost/Listings/Classes_MixerHostViewController_m.html

Comment: The thing is, your main view controller is not always going to be on the screen while the app goes to background, i.e. it won't become a first responder if a modal is on the screen.

Comment: @pablasso it might be, depending on the app.  But not in all cases, I agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation explains it very well.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html

Answer (score 0):

One thing that seems to influence this behavior is any category options you set for your AVAudioSession using setCategory:withOptions:error: instead of just setCategory:error:. In particular, from trial and error, it appears that if you set AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers you will not get remote control events; the now playing controls will still control the iPod app. If you set AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers you will get remote control events, but it seems like there may be some ambiguity regarding which app is controlled. Setting the categoryOptions to 0 or just calling setCategory:error: works best.