# iPhone - keep radio running in background

Tags: iphone, ios4, background

I am creating a Radio application , in that I want to keep my radio running even though the application goes to the background.

i.e. streaming must be continued , right now it gets stopped.

Please help me out from this situation

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "Required background modes" entry to your application .plist. This is an array, add an item of "App plays audio".

if you look at the plist source, it'll be:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not working. I am using ios 4.1 , and in simulator the same does not worked. I copied the code in to my .plist file. Do I making any mistake please suggest !!

Comment: I believe there are methods to get it working in the simulator, but I've had no need to look into them.

Answer (score 1):

This might be worth looking into:

[iPhone ios4 - Replacing iPod dock icon whilst playing background audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361619/iphone-ios4-replacing-ipod-dock-icon-whilst-playing-background-audio-stream)