# How to run a radio streaming in background in iOS

Tags: ios6, multitasking, http-live-streaming

Im creating a radio app in iOS. Now I want to make it running in background. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473870/iphone-keep-radio-running-in-background) I referred. I want to know what is this "App plays audio". I give the same in plist. But it doesn't play continuously. I tester on a device. Plz help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this could help you .
you can find the answer at this link

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54158-playing-a-radio-stream-in-the-background-ios-4.html