# How to show the play icon in the statusbar of my iPhone / iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, audio, background

I made an app which allows an audio file (http://site/file.mp3) to be played in the background.
This all works great. I only want an play icon to be visible like [this statusbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsxLl.png)
See the 'play' icon in the top right.

I've googled my brains out and can't seem to find anything that explains how to achieve this.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need this in your plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Other than that - it might be a part of linking your app to the iPod controls; which is answered here: [iPhone ios4 - Replacing iPod dock icon whilst playing background audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361619/iphone-ios4-replacing-ipod-dock-icon-whilst-playing-background-audio-stream)

Comment: I added the key UIBackgroundModes to my plist, else I wouldn't be able to continue playing the audio when I close the app or 'turn off' my iPad.

I'll give that link a try, thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm!
Follow-up: How can I receive events from these (http://www.rogueamoeba.com/utm/wp-content/uploads/images/20100622tray.png) buttons?

Comment: That's done in the link I posted - by using remoteControlReceivedWithEvent

Comment: Ah I found the problem, I called the beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents and becomeFirstResponder instance methods from within the -(void)viewDidLoad and not in -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: adding audio to UIBackgroundModes does not make the play icon appear in the statusbar